# Refs methods in vue-composition-api

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

there is a component with a ref like this:

```html
<template>
  <custom-component
     ref="func"
  />
</template>

<script setup>
const func = ref();
</script>
```

and inside the component there is a function like this:

```
const helloWorld = () => {
    console.log('hello World');
}
```

how do i get accsess to helloWorld function from the parent component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your child component is also using `<script setup>`, the component's definitions are closed by default (not exposed).

You can manually expose the method with [`defineExpose`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose) in the child component:

```html
// CustomComponent.vue
<script setup>
const helloWorld = /*...*/

defineExpose({
  helloWorld
})
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-expose-api-in-script-setup?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)